# convert data time to a desired format in js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to convert `2022-09-13T08:06:12.328+0000` to `13 September at 1:36 PM` using javascript. In order to make things easier, I thought to install moment js and tried the conversion as below.

```
console.log(moment('2022-09-13T08:06:12.328+0000').calendar());
```

But it will print the output as `Yesterday at 1:36 PM`. So is there any way to change the format as I expected above(`13 September at 1:36 PM`) or any other best way to achieve it?

Comment: Yes, it's on the first page of momentjs.com

Comment: On a side note, [you probably shouldn't be using moment for new development](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this format :

```js
console.log(moment('2022-09-13T08:06:12.328+0000').format('D MMMM [at] h:mm A'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format it

```
const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
new Date('2022-09-13T08:06:12.328+0000').toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options)
```